# How to get User properties in Dynamic 365 CRM Client Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I've been tasked with making a button enabled/disabled depending on the value of a certain field (`pt_maxamount`) in our Dynamic 365 CRM app. In looking at the Javascript for the form, I see where I can do the following to get the current user:

```
function GetUser() {
  var UserId = Xrm.Page.context.getUserId();
 var UserName = Xrm.Page.context.getUserName();
 alert(UserId + " " + UserName);
}
```

My question is, once I've gotten the current user's ID, can I use that to "lookup" the user and get the value of that user's `pt_maxvalue`property?

I'm new to Dynamics 365 CRM, so I've been thrown into the deep end of the pool. I'm sorry if my question isn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user data is held on the system user entity, so you will need to make a Web API call to get the data (assuming your JavaScript isnt running on the user entity).

[`retrieveRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/retrieverecord)

```
Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord("systemuser", UserId , "?$select=pt_maxvalue").then(
    function success(result) {
        console.log("Max value: " + result.pt_maxvalue);
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, @james, I appreciate the help!